# Rethinkdb filter on an earlier query

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have a table "posts" with "timestamp".

Now I want from all user that have more than 1 post, to get all posts EXCEPT the most recent post.

With this query I can successfully check the users who have more than 1 post:

```
r.table("post")
  .group('userId')
  .count()
  .ungroup()
  .filter(r.row("reduction").gt(1))
```

I can get the last post of a specific user by doing

```
r.table("post")
.filter({userId: 'xxx'})
.max('timestamp')
```

Now I need to tie those somehow together, and then compare the timestamp from each row with the max('timestamp') to see if they are not equal. The following is what I had but it's obviously wrong

```
.filter(r.row('timestamp').ne(r.row('timestamp').max('timestamp')('timestamp')))
```

Any advice how I bring all this together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
r.table('post')
.group({
    index: 'userId'
})
.ungroup()
.filter(function(doc) { 
    return doc('reduction').count().gt(1)
})
.group('group')('reduction')
.nth(0)
.orderBy(
    r.desc('timestamp')
).skip(1)
```

With reservations for syntax errors; I built this query using python and then converted it to javascript. Especially unsure about the `.nth(0)` part, never used it in javascript. In python it's just `[0]`.